# Blazor server on MVC core getting error 500 when loading blazor.server.js [.NET8]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

So I'm testing this blazor server on our existing MVC core project using the latest .NET 8,

when running this error is always showing:
The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: Blazor static files

[image]

I followed the tutorial on microsoft:

```
services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents();

app.UseStaticFiles();
  //blazor
  app.MapBlazorHub();
  app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

when removing AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
in MapRazorComponents the blazor js file is loading but onlick trigger event is not working

Comment: Funny! After posting this I removed the app.MapBlazorHub(); and all works :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Net7 and below you use `app.MapBlazorHub()` to configure the Blazor Server HTTP request pipeline.

In Net8 [with it's render modes] `.AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()` configures the HTTP request pipeline to support the specific render mode.

You can't do both.

Note: `.AddInteractiveServerComponents()` configures the necessary services for the specific render mode.

Answer (score 0):

Funny! After posting this I removed the app.MapBlazorHub(); and all works :D